# Why would someone use this type of cast in C? The reference of a float is cast to an int pointer and then dereferenced

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I was reading about Carmack's fast inverse square root algorithm and noticed this:

```
float x;
// ... //
int i = *(int*)&x;
```

Why would someone choose to use this weird type of casting instead of just the following?

```
int i = (int)x;
```

Comment: Carmack didn't actually write the algorithm; see the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root#History_and_investigation).

Answer (score 28):

That's different.

`int i = (int) x;` will cast `float` to `int`, which will simply truncate it.

`int i = *(int *) &x;` will load into `i` the same bits that are currently stored in `x`. The result is something totally different from truncating `x`.

Comment: And why would one choose the second options? The only reason I can think of it that they want to directly manipulate the bit representation of a float.

Comment: That's the idea I think.

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea. I was curious since it seems like a pretty useless idea unless you already know the characteristic/mantissa float format, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root explains that.

Comment: Manipulating the bit representation of the float as if it was an int is the whole idea behind the algorithm. It is exploiting the bit-format in a clever way to do the calculation.

Comment: Just as a note: This code invokes undefined (or at the least implementation-defined) behavior according to the C standard, because it relies on a specific representation for float values (and possible violates the strict aliasing rule). However, it works (used to work) in specific compilers, that's why it can be useful.

Comment: One minor detail: `(int)x` will truncate, not round.

Comment: @sleske - I'm curious: *This* code -- as shown -- invokes %$! defined behavior? I'd have though it's rather defined (*as long as* both types hold 32 bit), namely that the `int` will hold the bit pattern of the `float`. The bit pattern of the float may be unspecified though(?)

Comment: Finally, as the C standard does not mandate a representation or `signed int` (only for `unsigned int`), technically the result of the cast could be a trap representation, which would invoke undefined behaviour when used. AFAIK no modern platform actually has trap representations for `signed int`, but the standard would allow it.

Comment: The C standard may not mandate a representation for `float`, but nearly everyone uses the IEEE 754 standard: http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/

Comment: I believe a union could be used to sidestep the strict aliasing issue. The representation issue remains, of course.

Comment: @MartinBa The C standard didn't define the representation of its data types in memory, just the values they could store. This is still causing lots of fun today (stop using `long` to denote a 64-bit integer already, dammit!), but was very important for multi-platform capabilities back when C was grown. There were plenty of ways to represent C types in memory, and completely different approaches to working with them - the only reason this isn't that big of a deal anymore is that modern desktop CPUs are almost identical in details like this. Embedded CPUs are still tricky, though :)

Comment: @CorleyBrigman Nearly everyone uses IEEE-754 now, yes. The C standard comes from an older time :P

Comment: @Martin Ba -- sleske was right. This violates the strict aliasing rule. The compiler can optimize that code away (or it could call `erase_harddrive`). Or it might do what you expect it to do today, but not with the next compiler release. It happens to work on some computers. It's better to use type punning (a union with an `int` and `float` member), for which there is no extra cost. Note however that type punning is UB in C++. Compilers are getting very good at optimizing. A call to `memcpy` might well be just as fast; a good compiler will inline that call to `memcpy` to copy 4 bytes.

Comment: @Luaan - IEEE 754 dates back to 1985, at least as old as C89. (though I am aware, C compilers existed long before that).

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy: Truncating is a form of rounding. Specifically, it rounds towards zero.

Answer (score 15):

It's called [type punning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning). It'll interpret the `float` as an `int`. Meaning, the bit representation is exactly copied.

It's a potentially dangerous operation, since some bit representations of floating point integers might be trap representations as integers (not the case with IEEE-754 floats and 2s complement integers, though).

Additionally, it might not work anymore, due to being undefined behaviour as per C standard. It's violating the strict aliasing rule.

C only supports accessing variable of a different type via `memcpy`.

This is the valid standard C way of writing the operation:

```
int y; float x = 42.0f;
memcpy(&y, &x, sizeof(x));
```

C99 added another way of doing this, by using a `union`:

```
union { int y; float x; } u = { .x = 42.0f };
int y = u.y;
```

Comment: Doesn't the union thing violate strict aliasing too?

Comment: @Random832 Depends on the C standard you're using. Since C99, it's not a violation anymore. Since most compilers somewhat allowed this before as well, the standard made it official.

Comment: I'm curious if there is a performance difference between the two approaches (type punning vs unions).

Comment: @Dai Both is type punning. They're just different ways how to achieve it. If they're different in terms of performance depends on the compiler, but a clever optimising compiler might turn both into the very same assembly (both clang and gcc do that). Example: https://godbolt.org/g/6vVdqL

Comment: @Random832, no the union thing most certainly does not violate strict aliasing. It is specifically allowed.